# 502 log into django admin gunicorn nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I manage to deploy my django application with [this tutorial from digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn)
but I have problem to log into application with django admin panel.

I get `502 Bad Gateway` when I write correct login and password, gunicorn workers reboots and then I can go into admin panel logged in, sometimes after this error occurs again. Application has one view/template outside of admin use and it works correctly.

Did someone have similar problem?

Comment: What exception is logged when your django process dies?

Comment: `[2020-03-05 17:17:32 +0000] [2238] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2238
[2020-03-05 17:17:32 +0000] [2239] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2239
[2020-03-05 17:17:32 +0000] [2240] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2240
[2020-03-05 17:17:32 +0000] [2235] [DEBUG] 3 workers
[2020-03-05 17:17:42 +0000] [2239] [DEBUG] GET /admin/
[2020-03-05 17:17:42 +0000] [2243] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2243

` there is none

Comment: how do i format this :D

Comment: `../env/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8001 --workers 3 --access-logfile '-' --error-logfile '-' --log-level debug myapp.wsgi` i start gunicorn workers with this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a python version. On my local machine i had python 3.7.6 and django 3.0
and in production there was python 3.7.0 and django 3.0 does have some problem with it.
I downgraded django to 2.2 and problem is gone.

Comment: For me same problem occurred with python 3.9.4 & django 3.2.3.
I downgraded to python 3.8.9 and it worked fine.